# Xcode: CKAsset in CloudKit

Tags: cloudkit, ckasset

in my Code below,

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *localPath = [[paths objectAtIndex: 0] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"temporary.png"];
    NSLog(@"local path=%@", localPath);
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.scriptPicture.image) writeToFile:localPath atomically:YES];
    //[opData.scripts writeToFile:localPath atomically:YES];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:localPath]) {
        NSLog(@"file is exist");
        NSURL *fileurl=[NSURL URLWithString:localPath];
        CKAsset *myfile=[[CKAsset alloc] initWithFileURL:fileurl];
        //postRecrod[@"scriptPicture"]=myfile;
        [postRecrod setObject:myfile forKey:@"scriptPicture"];
}
```

error will occur in the line of "`CKAsset *myfile=[[CKAsset alloc] initWithFileURL:fileurl];`"
error message is below:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Non-file URL'

I don't know how to solve this and search web all night long, but no help.
Please help me ! I am a code beginner !

Answer (score 2):

You are building your `fileurl` incorrectly.

Replace this line:

```
NSURL *fileurl=[NSURL URLWithString:localPath];
```

with this one:

```
NSURL *fileurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:localPath];
```

Always use the `fileURLWithPath:` method to create a file URL from a file path. Use `URLWithString:` when creating a URL for strings that represent a proper URL starting with a scheme (such as http:, mailto:, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I think your string will start with file://
Could you try changing it to something like this:

In Swift:

```
CKAsset(fileURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("temporary", ofType: "png")!))
```